# does every elliptic curve E/S have infinitely many sections after passing to an etale extension of S?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let E/S be an elliptic curve, where S is any scheme. Must there exist a scheme $S'$, etale and surjective over $S$, such that the pullback $E' := E\times_S S'$ has infinitely (or even > 1) many sections over $S'$?

References would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want $S'\to S$ be surjective ? Is $S$ really arbitrary ?

Comment: you're right, I've edited.

Comment: This should be OK if $S$ is quasi-compact, unless you want $S'\to S$ be etale surjective *and finite* (in which case I don't think the answer is positive).